# Failure in @AfterClass causes rest of tests to skip, TestNG

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I have an xml file with test classes.This is my testng suite xml. Each test class, has the following structure:

```
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass(){
}

@Test(dataProvider="Mail Information")
public void mailSend(String to,String subject,String body) throws Exception{
}

@AfterClass{
}
```

When I mistakenly put a null object in `AfterClass`, the test correctly failed, with `java.lang.NullPointerException`, but instead of continuing to the other tests of the suite, all the other tests became Skipped.

I assume that they become skipped, because their `@beforeClass` became skipped. So I think that the real problem is that a failure in `AfterClass`, somehow affected the BeforeClasses of the following tests in suite.

How can we handle such problem?

Comment: Ideally i wouldnt expect the next classes to fail.  Also, that test itself also should not fail if afterclass has an error.  Can you share  your xml which you are using to drive your tests?

Comment: @niharika_neo Yes that's ideally the behavior i was anticipating myself, according to theory. Here's the xml I used:
(Part1)
`<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test-Suite">
 <parameter name="rcHost" value="localhost" />
<parameter name="rcPort" value="4444" />
<parameter name="targetHostUrl" value="http://en.aegeanair.com"/>
<parameter name="debugging" value="true" /> 
<parameter name="browser" value="firefox" /> 
<parameter name="profile" value="default"/>
<parameter name="driverType" value="webdriver" />
<parameter name="actionsLogging" value="true" />`

Comment: (Part2)
 `<listeners>
  <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"></listener> 
    </listeners> 
 <test name="simpleTests" preserve-order="true">
 <classes>
  <class name="test.SearchHotel" />
  <class name="test.SearchHotel2" />     
  </classes>

 </test>
</suite>`

Comment: Nothing apparently wrong in xml.  Can you edit your question and put the xml there.  Also add "how did you accidently put null" in afterclass..probably the code.

Comment: @niharika_neo : i performed an action, in after class, in an object that i had forgotten to instantiate.This is how i "achieved" null pointer!

Answer (score 4):

After a long long time, I found the solution to my problem..
It all goes away, by adding in the suite tag, the entryconfigfailurepolicy, and set it to continue, in your suite xml files like this:

```
    <suite name="Test-Suite" configfailurepolicy="continue">
```

By default the value of the parameter was skip, which was causing tests to skip, if a failed configuration occured.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but as per TestNG [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) it should solve your issue. Set the alwaysRun attribute to true for each of the test method.

Comment: All test methods are marked `@Test(alwaysRun = true`

Answer (score 0):

I try this way "alwaysRun = true" to always run the function on @AfterClass annotation. Although any @Test has NullPointerException

```
@AfterClass(groups = { "smoke" }, alwaysRun = true)
private void stoptream() {
        Stream.tryForceStop3times(id, data);
}
```